# Custom Class - Change attribute in array

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy, operator-keyword

I belivie I am looking for an operator for changes in an array for Python. I have created a custom class for a numpy array matrix.

I would like to change a single element in an array, which also changes the numbers of zeros, which is what the class below do.

```
class MyClass(object):
def __init__(self, Matrix):
      self._nonzero=len(Matrix[nonzero(Matrix)])
      self._Matrix=Matrix
def set_Matrix(self,Matrix):
    self._Matrix=Matrix
    self._nonzero=len(Matrix[nonzero(Matrix)])
def get_Matrix(self):
    return self._Matrix
def get_nonzero(self):
    return self._nonzero    

Matrix=property(fget=get_Matrix,fset=set_Matrix)         
nonzero =property(fget=get_nonzero,fset=set_Matrix)
```

If I have the following input, I get the following result

```
a= array([[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]) 
g=MyClass(a)
g.nonzero
>>>4 #Correct
g.Matrix=array([[0, 2],
                [3, 4]])
g.nonzero
>>>3 #Correct
```

But I want to change a single element in the numpy array matrix in an easier way. When I try the following I get it wrong:

```
g.Matrix[0,0]=0
g.Matrix
>>>array([[0, 2],
          [3, 4]])
g.nonzero
>>>4 #incorrect
```

**EDIT**

I belive I solved it with this code. I am not sure it is optimized, but it does work.

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, Matrix):
      self._Matrix=Matrix
   def set_Matrix(self,Matrix):
      self._Matrix=Matrix
   def get_Matrix(self):
      return self._Matrix
   def set_nonzero(self,Matrix):
       self._Matrix=Matrix
       self._nonzero=len(Matrix[nonzero(Matrix)])
   def get_nonzero(self):
      self._Matrix=Matrix
      self._nonzero=len(Matrix[nonzero(Matrix)])
      return self._nonzero

   Matrix=property(fget=get_Matrix,fset=set_Matrix)         
   nonzero =property(fget=get_nonzero,fset=set_nonzero)
```

Comment: `nonzero` is only being set once. You aren't resetting it after changing the value of your array. If you want it to be reset each time you will have to do so explicitly.

Comment: I tried to use use def set_nonzero(self,Matrix)....

But that did not work either sadly. So I know what is wrong and understand why. But I do no know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that nonzero is only calculated when your object is first instantiated. The best option is make nonzero evaluate rather than return the stored value.

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, Matrix):
      self._Matrix=Matrix
   def set_Matrix(self,Matrix):
      self._Matrix=Matrix
   def get_Matrix(self):
      return self._Matrix
   def get_nonzero(self):
      return len(_Matrix[nonzero(_Matrix)])
```

or alternately if you want nonzero cached you could hide the matrix from users of the class and overload the index operator to get to it e.g.

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, Matrix):
      self.__Matrix=Matrix
      self._nonzero=len(__Matrix[nonzero(__Matrix)])
   def get_nonzero(self):
      return len(__Matrix[nonzero(Matrix)])
   def __getitem__(self,index):
      return self.__Matrix[index]
   def __setitem__(self, index, value)
      self.__Matrix[index] = value
      self._nonzero = len(__Matrix[nonzero(__Matrix)])
   def get_nonzero(self):
      return self._nonzero
```

For either include:

```
Matrix=property(fget=get_Matrix,fset=set_Matrix)         
nonzero =property(fget=get_nonzero,fset=set_nonzero)
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to be able to show the user both nonzero and matrix at all the time. I tried to implement your code. But when I do the example above I now get:
g.nonzero
>>>8

Comment: If you tried the first one(which I think is the better option here) I had a missing _ before the Matrix in the get_nonzero function, I've corrected it now.

Comment: I tried the first one. If I use it only, I do not return anything at "g.nonzero", because "MyClass" object has no attribute "nozero", which I understand.

If I on the other hand use the Matrix=Property(...). As in the OP I get the following message "name '_Matrix' is not defined". If I change the remove the _ in get_nonzero I still get 8, no matter the size of the matrix.

Comment: Sorry yeah you need to include the nonzero method from your origonal

Comment: No problem. It is solved. I edited the OP. Thanks again